# Explanation of Java Lanaguage Specification(7) 12.6.1. Implementing Finalization

Tags: java, finalizer

Below is the block of text taken from section 12.6.1 of JLS(7).

## ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

For example, consider the Finalizer Guardian pattern:

```
class Foo {
    private final Object finalizerGuardian = new Object() {
        protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
            /* finalize outer Foo object */
        }
    }
}
```

The finalizer guardian forces super.finalize to be called if a subclass overrides finalize and does not explicitly call super.finalize.

If these optimizations are allowed for references that are stored on the heap, then a Java compiler can detect that the finalizerGuardian field is never read, null it out, collect the object immediately, and call the finalizer early. This runs counter to the intent: the programmer probably wanted to call the Foo finalizer when the Foo instance became unreachable. This sort of transformation is therefore not legal: the inner class object should be reachable for as long as the outer class object is reachable.

Transformations of this sort may result in invocations of the finalize method occurring earlier than might be otherwise expected. In order to allow the user to prevent this, we enforce the notion that synchronization may keep the object alive. If an object's finalizer can result in synchronization on that object, then that object must be alive and considered reachable whenever a lock is held on it.

Note that this does not prevent synchronization elimination: synchronization only keeps an object alive if a finalizer might synchronize on it. Since the finalizer occurs in another thread, in many cases the synchronization could not be removed anyway.

## -------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Question 1 :In reference to the last two paragraphs,is this what we need to do?

```
 class Foo {
        private final Object finalizerGuardian = new Object() {
            protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
                   synchronized(this){
                          /*
                           *Some code goes here
                           */
                          }
                /* finalize outer Foo object */
            }
        }
    }
```

Question: When does synchronization elemination occur?